# problems reading a long text file in R

Tags: r

I crawled all of youtubes comments and stored in a text file given below (lots of wierd characters)

I am trying to load the file in `R` using:

```
doc <- read.table("C:/Users/schatterjee/Desktop/projects/text mining/youtube_comments.txt")
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in scan (file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,: Line 1 was not 17 elements
```

How can I load this text in the doc variable?

youtube_comments.txt :

```
High levelï»¿ fshion film,like a movie even it is short but not mediocre
Most People.....
Look at people with money and think they "got lucky" or have a skill most peopleï»¿ don't have.....
Is belief, A plan & Action .....
Learn how a fed up Wal-Mart Cashier quit his job 60 days after learning this simple secret.....
Visit:
MysteryToSuccess(dot)com
ã€?è˜‹æžœæ—¥å ±ã€‘å†?æœ‰å•†æˆ¶è¢«æ³•åœ‹å??ç‰ŒLVï¼ˆLOUIS VUITTONï¼‰æŒ‡ä¾µçŠ¯ç‰ˆæ¬Šï¼Œè¦?æ±‚è³ å„Ÿå?Šç™»å ±é?“æ­‰ã€‚å…©é–“åˆ†åˆ¥åœ¨æ—ºè§’å?Šæ·±æ°´åŸ—çš„å•†æˆ¶æŒ‡ï¼Œæ—©å‰?æ”¶åˆ°LVä¾†ä¿¡ï¼ŒæŒ‡å…©åº—å”®è³£çš„æ‰‹è¢‹ä¾µçŠ¯LVè¢‹æ‰£ï¼ˆS-Lockï¼‰ç‰ˆæ¬Šã€‚æœ‰åº—æ?±è?²ç¨±ï¼Œä¸?çŸ¥è©²æ¬¾è¨­è¨ˆæ˜¯LVå°ˆåˆ©ï¼Œå¸Œæœ›å°?æ–¹é«˜æŠ¬è²´æ‰‹ã€‚è¨˜è€…ï¼šå¾?é›²åº­ã€€æ¢?ç‘žå¸†

å…©é–“è¢«æŒ‡ä¾µæ¬Šçš„åº—èˆ–ï¼Œåˆ†åˆ¥æ˜¯æ—ºè§’å…†è?¬å•†å ´ä¸€æ¨“çš„æ™‚è£?åº—ã€Œnabu nabuã€?å?Šæ·±æ°´åŸ—æ±?å·žè¡—ã€Œæº?æ³°ç´?æ‰£ã€?ã€‚å‰?è€…è¢«æŒ‡å‡ºå”®çš„ä¸€æ¬¾æ‰‹è¢‹ä¾µæ¬ŠLVè¢‹æ‰£è¨­è¨ˆï¼ˆS-Lockï¼‰ï¼›å¾Œè€…äº¦æŒ‡å‡ºå”®çš„ä¸€å€‹é¡žä¼¼ç…™ç›’å°?è¢‹è¢‹æ‰£å?Œæ¨£ä¾µæ¬Šã€‚S-Lockæ˜¯LVå…¶ä¸­ä¸€æ¬¾åœ¨é¦™æ¸¯è¨»å†Šå•†æ¨™ï¼Œåœ¨å¤šæ¬¾æ‰‹è¢‹å?Šæ‰‹è…•çš®å¸¶å?‡è¦‹è©²è¨­è¨ˆã€‚ï»¿
Arizona muse.ï»¿ (:
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `?readLines`.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9068397/1036500 ?