# Importing a single vector from a text file as a variable in R

Tags: r, import

I have saved a vector in a .txt file so that I could plot it (something like c(0.55,....)).

I am trying to import it directly into a variable, but somehow I can't.

I played a bit with the scan() function with no success thinking that the raw() argument was the answer.

I have tried this solution [Import text file as single character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string)

but this doesn't solve my problem.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your text file has R syntax in it (`c(...)`) then

```
x <- source("myfile.txt")[["value"]]
```

should work.