# Load file with multiple delimiters in R

Tags: r, delimiter

I have a large text file with multiple delimiters - ":", ";", ",". All lines start with :2015. Here is an example of a line:

> :2015,01,04;22,06,07,57:1587.0059,1582.1625,1577.2192,1571.9540,1561.7333,1546.7213,1531.9143,1517.3482:1587.2206,1582.2081,1577.1512,1572.1362,1561.2966,1547.7744,1533.1818,1516.6925:1587.4020,1582.1017,1577.2475,1572.2528,1562.0818,1546.2844,1532.8708,1516.4988:1587.1609,1582.2521,1577.2482,1572.2127,1562.2775,1547.7381,1532.7753,1516.0095

How should I load this file into R? Some lines have this irregularity that two lines are present together on one line. How can I deal with this?

> **:2015**,01,04;22,06,07,58:1587.0048,1582.1615,1577.2197,1571.9543,1561.7341,1546.7314,1531.9131,1517.3372:1587.2196,1582**:2015**,01,04;22,06,07,99:1587.0061,1582.1610,1577.2170,1571.9536,1561.8633,1547.0056,1531.8030,1516.9904:1587.2205,1582.2067,1577.1493,1572.1346,1561.3149,1547.6513,1533.2912,1516.6911:1587.4008,1582.1001,1577.2466,1572.2508,1561.9674,1546.0941,1532.9294,1516.6921:1587.1605,1582.2502,1577.2468,1572.2109,1562.0034,1547.5732,1532.9829,1516.0305

Comment: So to be clear, what's the desired output for your sample input?

Answer (score 2):

You can read a file as a character vector (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069670/1898580)):

```
fileName <- 'foo.txt'
s <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

Then, you can use `strsplit` to separate lines:

```
L <- strsplit(s,split='2015:')
```

and for each line, use `strsplit` again to separate records

```
lapply(L,strsplit,split=',|;|:')
```