# Read a long RNA string in txt file in R

Tags: r, string, bioconductor

I have an RNA string on text format file. I want to import/read it from the txt file for translate function of Biostrings package in R.

I tried readRNAStringSet before but this function reads FASTA and FASTQ formats, however, my file is not FASTA or FASTQ but it's txt and I wanna read from that one.

In my file, there's no quotation mark but after the last code, there's space.
Eventually, When I read this RNA string, I want to translate it to its protein amino acids using "translate" function in Biostrings package.

As an example, I have the RNA string bellow in "txt" file, there's no quotations and no other sign in the file and there's only one string:

> AUGCCGGUAAAGCGUGUCACAGAACUCCAUUUACUAUUAUGCCUUUGUGCGGGAGGAAGUUUCAGAAAGUACAUUCAUCC‌​UGGA

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and describe better what you want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string

Comment: I just looked into Biostrings package...you need to use the readRNAStringSet function. Make sure your input file is FASTA or FASTQ formatted

Comment: Thank you guys for your consideration. here is one example:

Comment: AUGCCGGUAAAGCGUGUCACAGAACUCCAUUUACUAUUAUGCCUUUGUGCGGGAGGAAGUUUCAGAAAGUACAUUCAUCCUGGACGCAUCU

Comment: Just in a text file.

Comment: I tried readRNAStringSet before and exactly my problem is that my file is not FASTA or FASTQ but it's txt and I wanna read from that one.

Comment: @arado1 perhaps you should put these notes as an edit to the original question.  That way people do not have to read the comments to see what you want

Comment: Sorry, I thought that my question is clear. I'd edit it if I could!

Comment: @arado1 There's an edit button just under the question...

Comment: Thanks Tensibai. I'll add more explanation.

Comment: @arado1 1) prefix people with @ (so we get a notification when you answer) 2) Please use the enter Key and try to write it in paragraphs, as is it's an unreadable blob of text.

Comment: @Tensibai Is it better now?

Comment: Much better yes ;) you have my upvote for listening to advices and putting the effort (I just quoted the file content as a last modification, the functions and class type could have been embedded with quotes too, but it's really much easy to read now)

Comment: (last note on So notifications, post author is always notified ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `readLines` and convert to `RNAStringSet` afterwards:

```
> writeLines(c("AUGC", "AGCU", "UUGA", "CGAU"), "foo") # Dummy input
> RNAStringSet(readLines("foo"))
  A RNAStringSet instance of length 4
    width seq
[1]     4 AUGC
[2]     4 AGCU
[3]     4 UUGA
[4]     4 CGAU
```