# R Letter Frequencies from Text File

Tags: r

I'm trying to pull the letter frequencies from a text file. I want it to create two columns.

The text file for example might have "aabbbbccc".

I want the output to be...

```
Key    Count
a      2
b      4
c      3
```

Here's what I have now. I'm sure it's wrong...

```
mydata3 <- read.table("/Users/ChristopherFlach/Documents/ds710fall2016assignment6/encryptedA.txt", header = FALSE)
as.data.frame(table(strsplit(mydata3,"")))                    
attach(mydata3)
```

Comment: `table(strsplit("aabbbbccc", ''))`

Comment: as.data.frame(table(strsplit("aabbbbccc", ''))) is closer

Comment: If you're using read.table you will be getting a table of data rather than a vector of data.  Have a look at the following, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string which may work for you.

Comment: There are probably more letters than you think, consider non-English languages and letter frequencies will be different for different languages.