# Error when importing text from files (readChar Error in file.info(filename[i]) : invalid filename argument)

Tags: r, invalid-argument

I was importing text from files following the code explained here by Tommy:

[Import text file as single character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string)

I imported the name of the files (which are in subfolders):

```
mydata <- as.data.frame(list.files(path="FolderWithFiles",
                                     full.names = FALSE, recursive = 
TRUE, ignore.case= TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE))
```

Then I was using a loop to import the content for all the files (the working directory is set to "FolderWithFiles"):

```
filename <- mydata$filename

x<-(1:245)
y<-c(1:245)

for ( i in x) {

  y[i]  <- readChar(filename[i] , file.info(filename[i])$size)

}
```

This used to work until I changed some of the files. Now I keep getting this error and I cannot solve it:

```
Error in file.info(filename[i]) : invalid filename argument
```

Comment: Do you need to fix your working directory?

Comment: `file.info` needs a path, not just the file name, unless your working directory is set to the containing folder.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, the working directory is indeed set to the containing folder.

Comment: Did you change actual file names, and is that what broke it? It's possible you could have invalid characters in your file names.

Comment: all the file names are similar to this, where the first name and the year are the subfolders:

""Section/yyyy/Journal-Argument_SubArgument-dd.mm.yyyy-comment.txt""

I just added the last part, I don't think the name is the problem. I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I post it for anyone experiencing the same error:

```
Error in file.info(filename[i]) : invalid filename argument
```

For some reason after updating R, it started importing the names of files as factors rather than characters.
It was enough to add:

```
mydata$filename <- as.character(mydata$filename)
```

Comment: When you create a data frame, character vectors are automatically converted to factors. You can either specify `as.data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, or you can go the tidy route and create a `tibble`.