# How to read unformat txt file in r

Tags: r

I want to read below data example in r.

The first column is country name, but when i read in r, it give some error of sep?

My code:

```
df <- read.table('df.txt', header=T)
```

My data look like

```
column1 column 2
spain      20
united kingdom 37
germany 97
republic of china 12
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are different number of columns for each row (using the delimiter `sep=" "`). Try

```
df = readLines("df.txt")
```

This will give you a vector of strings, where each element is a row in `df.txt`. You can parse the lines further with

```
countries = strsplit(df, " ")
countries = sapply(countries, function(x) paste(x[-length(x)], collapse = " "))
```

to get the countries.

`strsplit` returns a list, and `sapply(...)` removes the last element of item in the list, then pastes them all back together.

Your question is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string).